# Adding Name To Actionscript Pie Chart

Tags: flash, apache-flex, charts, pie-chart

In actionscript 3.0, I want to attach a display name to an entire pie chart component. For instance, something like the years added below each chart in the following image:

[image: chart]

All I've been able to find so far is (as was done in generating this image) adding a separate text field component that includes the chart name. I've been over Adobe's docs and I can't find any way to add a name/label that goes with the entire chart, but I wanted to check if anyone knows of a method I've missed.

(adding a separate text field will work, it just seems like there should be a way to attach the name to the chart)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no such title for a pie chart, and I don't think there is any for other charts in the Flex framework.  The title should be added external to the chart component.  Such approach would provide greater flexibility to configure how the title should look, its placement, interactivity, etc.